# Changing the value of Binding depending on value in db

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

**My Question:** How can I check if the binding has a value? And based on the value, how can I change the content of the binding then?

Atm I managed to get the value I have in db. But instead of showing the Mailaddress in the 2nd column I want to change the value to f.e. "exist" or if there's a `null` value in the db to "exist not".

**XAML**

```
<ListView x:Name="lstvw_test" Height="120" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Student" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ...}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Mailaddress" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ...}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I cannot figure out if its possible to do this only in the XAML or if I have to check it in my code (prefer XAML). I am working with VB.NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pure XAML solution would be possible with a DataTrigger:

```
<GridView>
    <GridViewColumn Header="Student" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Student}"/>
    <GridViewColumn Header="Mailaddress">
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Exists"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Mailaddress}" 
                                             Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Does not exist"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
</GridView>
```

You may add another DataTrigger with `Value=""` to check for an empty string.

Comment: nice i think thats what i am looking for. still have a question, why do i use a textblock inside there? (sry if this is a dumb question)

Comment: You'll have to declare the Style with the DataTrigger somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new string property in the view model that would be set to "exists" or "doesn't exist" based on the value of Mailaddress. Then use this property for your column binding.

Comment: iam sry iam a newbee, how can i check the value of my binding in my xaml and change it afterwards to the new string?

Answer (score 1):

One of the way you can achieve it using IValueConvertor

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/

Comment: can i also just check if the value is `null` or `not null` instead of fixed strings?